# Entity Framework- Creating Index and ForeignKey name (Oracle)

Tags: oracle, entity

I have problem with creating automatically names for Constraints and Indexes. After length of Constraint or Index exceeds 30 characters then the name is changed to f.e:

```
"FK_OT_PERSONAL_EQUI_1685080621"
```

Fortunately I saw that in my method there is parameter that is used to name specific constraints and indexes.

```
        CreateTable(
            "OTDBA.OT_PERSONAL_EQUIPMENT",
            c => new
                {
                    EQUIPMENT_ID = c.Decimal(nullable: false, precision: 10, scale: 0),
                    ACTIVE_TIME = c.Decimal(nullable: false, precision: 19, scale: 0),
                    SHOW_MODE = c.Decimal(nullable: false, precision: 10, scale: 0),
                    RESOURCE_ID = c.Decimal(nullable: false, precision: 10, scale: 0),
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => t.EQUIPMENT_ID)
            .ForeignKey("OTDBA.OT_RESOURCES",  t => t.RESOURCE_ID, cascadeDelete: true,name: "FK_OT_EQUIPMENT_RESOURCES")
            .Index(t => t.RESOURCE_ID);
```

Unfortunately it doesn't work and if we check auto-generated script we have:

```
alter table "OTDBA"."OT_PERSONAL_EQUIPMENT" add constraint "FK_OT_PERSONAL_EQUI_1685080621" foreign key ("RESOURCE_ID") references "OTDBA"."OT_RESOURCES" ("RESOURCE_ID") on delete cascade
```

/

without including my change for FK_OT_EQUIPMENT_RESOURCES

Basic question. Why?